# Does Origin have any built in screenshot functionality?

Tags: origin

Origin is trying to edge its way onto Steam's turf, which seems to have been one of the major reasons for keeping Mass Effect 3 an Origin (and console!) exclusive.

Thing is, I use Steam for a lot more than simply buying games - I've also fallen in love with the Steam Screenshot service.

Does Origin have anything comparable? Or will I have to rely on third party software (like FRAPS, or... even running Origin through Steam?) to get my screenshots?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Origin does not support screenshots. 
You will have to use FRAPS or Steam to make them or the game's functionality if there is any.

Comment: I assume if you add the game to Steam "Games...Add a non-Steam game to the Library..." it will launch with the overlay which can take snaps for you.

Comment: Yes, thats right.

Comment: That doesn't help with some games like BF3. EA makes you launch that game from a browser so Steam can't put it's overlay.

Comment: Download Process Explorer from SysInternals, Launch the game using Origin, fire up Process Explorer and copy the exact command line used to launch the exe. Add it to Steam :)

Answer (score 3):

What i have become accustomed to doing is having microsoft paint open when i play my games.  When i do good in a match and im looking at the scoreboard i can just do a Print Screen and paste it into paint where i save it as an image.  Its not very conveniant but hey, at least its something!

Comment: While this is a decent substitute in most cases, I will point out for posterity that this does not necessarily work with full-screen games. (If it does not, you will simply paste a full black screen)

Comment: Or worse yet, it won't be an image of the game as it was when you pressed the button, but as it is now, when you paste it. I noticed this with a few games, ME: Andromeda, most recently.

Answer (score 3):

Although not provided by Origin itself, this shortcut works inside all Origin games:

- press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd>

This will not produce any sound nor visual effect and screenshots of all games are saved in the same folder: `%USERPROFILE%\Pictures\Screenshots`.

Using *Windows 10 version 1909* and *Origin Version 10.5.63*.

Comment: i have tried the Win+PrtScn and unfortunately it doesn't work with Origin at all because when i tried it i got what ever was on my desktop at the time.