# How do I take a screen shot in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3, origin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Origin have any built in screenshot functionality?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53523/does-origin-have-any-built-in-screenshot-functionality)

Print screen doesn't seem to work. Is there another way in ME3 or in the Origin overlay that will let me take a screen shot?  Or do I have to use Fraps?

Comment: Related: [Does Origin have any built in screenshot functionality](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/53523/3062)

Comment: The game does create a Screenshots folder in "My Documents\BioWare\Mass Effect 3\BIOGame\Screenshots" so it would seem that there is (or was) some built-in way to save a screenshot?

Comment: @GAThrawn even though the folder is in there, I've tried everything in game but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To take a screen shot in ME3, you'll have to switch over to Borderless Windowed mode to allow print screen to work properly.  Using Alt+PrintScreen captures just the ME3 window, allowing you to paste it into paint.

[image]

Comment: I know you already mentioned Fraps in your question, but I highly recommend someone simply grab the free version of [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/) instead of doing this. Smack a key and you've got a stored screenshot for later use. I used to use the printscreen method for taking screenshots in games and it's a lot more effort.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative, if you're using Steam, is to make [Steam launch Mass Effect 3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53932/200). Once done, hitting the Steam's Capture Screen hotkey (by default, <kbd>F12</kbd>).

Once done, hitting <kbd>F12</kbd> will capture the screen & can be uploaded to Steam Cloud.

Comment: ^^^ Mass Effect 3 is not in Steam, FYI.

Comment: @Sara it's not, but I've linked to my other answer where you *can* make steam launch Mass Effect 3