# How do I take a screenshot on Mass effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I need help taking screenshots in Mass Effect 3. I was able to put it on as a non-Steam game but when I load it up it, Steam thinks I shut it down as soon as. So I'm not able to take screenshots.

Comment: Which question are you referring to? please provide a link

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [How do I take a screen shot in Mass Effect 3?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/54419/27134), which was answered by [Does Origin have any built in screenshot functionality?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/53523/27134)

Answer (score 1):

Both Mass Effect 3 and Origin have no 'built in' functionality for taking screenshots.

Mass Effect 3 strangely enough does have a screenshots folder in it's installation directory, but this doesn't do anything and there is seemingly no functionality to fill it with screenshots. Your options are pretty much as follows;

- Run the game in fullscreen mode and use a third party application like FRAPS to take a screenshot
- [Run the game in borderless window mode and use print screen](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/54421/27134)
- [Use Steam to launch Mass Effect 3 and use Steam's screenshot functionality](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53932/27134)

Comment: Have you tried pressing the [Print screen button](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Print_screen)? Usually, when a game features a Screenshot folder, it will automatically save a screenshot upon pressing that button. Also, much less comfortable, but still valid: You can press the PrtScn button to create a screenshot on the clipboard, then open an image editor app, paste the screenshot inside, then save the image.

Comment: Pressing Print Screen in fullscreen mode results in no action. In order for print screen to work you need to be in borderless window mdoe. This is already covered above!

Answer (score 0):

You can always make a screen shot by using the `Print Screen` button (sometimes labeled `prt sc`) and then paste it into any image editor like `Paint` or `Gimp`.

Comment: Actually, some games don't work with print screen.

Comment: Really? Interesting. I've yet to encounter such a game and would be curious to know what mechanic prevents Print Screen from working.

Comment: Some games provide their own print screen function that automatically saves to a certain directory.

Comment: Mass Effect 3 does not allow screenshots when running in fullscreen mode, if you run in full screen mode (not borderless window) you will need to use a third party application like FRAPS.

Answer (score 0):

Mass Effect has a built in **Screenshots Directory**.

To take a screen shot in ME3, you'll have to switch over to **Borderless Windowed Mode** to allow print screen to work properly. Using Alt+PrintScreen captures just the ME3 window, allowing you to paste it into paint.